# The method 'getReferenceFromUrl' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseStorage'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have a problem with Firebase. I learned flutter using a video on youtube about how to delete data and images from `firebase`. And I have one function that deletes the image from `firestore` but I cannot use **getReferenceFromUrl()**. It shows the error

> The method 'getReferenceFromUrl' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseStorage'.

```
deleteFood(Food food, Function foodDeleted) async {
  if (food.image != null) {
    Reference storageReference =
        await FirebaseStorage.instance.getReferenceFromUrl(food.image);

    print(storageReference.path);

    await storageReference.delete();

    print('image deleted');
  }

  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Foods').doc(food.id).delete();
  foodDeleted(food);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getReferenceFromUrl` is depracated as you can see [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#storage).

You would need to call `ref()` with the path to the file in the storage.

As @puff mentioned in the comment the new API call would be `refFromURL('your_download_url')`

Comment: The most likely replacement method for `getReferenceFromUrl` is actually [`refFromURL`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/refFromURL.html). `ref()` takes a path, while `refFromURL` takes a download URL as far as I can tell.